# ASPX or Web Services?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

When using jQuery ajax inside a .NET website and i'm returning things like JSON, should you use a standard aspx page or should it be a web service?

I know web services are used for external interfaces etc... I just wondered what was normal practice?

Thanks

Comment: A standard ASPX page returns HTML, not JSON.

Comment: The choice is probably wider than that, i.e. .ashx, asmx, MVC, WebAPI, WCF or ServiceStack.

Comment: ok, i've started a debate now! lol... I will have to look into reasons for each then :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I think he was referring to System.Web.Services.WebMethod. As he is talking about calling ajax from Jquery.

Comment: @milanm - could be, but that is an ASMX.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, the System.Web.Services.WebMethod can be written in code behind .cs files also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web service is an exposed end point that is normally used as an API, or in other words its end user is typically another application rather than a user interface.

On the other hand, Static System.Web.Services.WebMethod can be used in any .aspx page or more typically in a .asmx (web service) file.

If your function requires a call from another application then use Web Services. In other cases use Web-Methods.

Comment: the static web methods inside the aspx pages are called page methods

Comment: Thats great thank you. Also, I do not want seperate projects for web services from my main application which I believe you need. So aspx it is with WebMethods I guess. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes that's right.As @Saranya, mentioned, static web methods inside the aspx page are called page methods.

Comment: You dont have to have separate projects for web services from your main app. you can have a service inside the web application itself..

Comment: oh I see, so you can basically have a web service inside a standard aspx (code-behind) page which just returns whatever object

Comment: thats a web service inside a web application project and not web service inside aspx:)